# How to insert string into other string at certain position in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

For my assignment, I'm trying to write Insert function like C++ insert.
My function should insert one string into other string at a certain  position.

**Inputs:**

```
destination : Be my friend today
source      : good
position    : 6
```

**Output**:

```
Be my good friend today
```

> How should I make room in the middle of the string ?

This is my code so far.

```
Insert PROC PROC uses edi esi ebx ecx,
                  destination:DWORD ,
                  source:DWORD,
                  position:DWORD

    mov  esi,destination          ;add esi address of str
    add  esi,position
    add  esi,4                     ;lenght of source
    mov  edi,destination           
    add  edi,position

    ;I don't know what should I do in here

    ;How should I make room in the middle of destination ?
    ;How should I insert at certain position + source length :-(
    ;Also, I shouldn't use loop and lea. 


    rep  movsb

    Insert ENDP
```

Comment: Try my answer and let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to avoid providing any code, because I have no intention of writing your assignment for you, but I will attempt to explain how you would accomplish it.

I am going to assume the following:

1) `destination` has enough memory at its address to hold the completed string without overwriting any other variables.

2) You actually want to insert `"good "` (with a trailing space), rather than `"good"`, since if you insert `"good"` you'll end up with `"Be my goodfriend today"` (without the space between good and friend).

3) You actually intended to specify position 5, rather than position 6, since C++ `insert` uses zero-based positions (position 0 is the first character, position 1 is the second, etc).

Your first step is to copy the right-hand portion of the string in order to make room.  You will copy the characters from the starting position for the insert, to the starting position plus the size of the string to insert, ending up with the following:

```
destination : Be my frienfriend today
```

There is one catch here though: you have to copy **backwards** from the end of `destination` to avoid overwriting characters that haven't been copied yet - if you start at offset 6 and copy that to offset 11, you will have overwritten the value of offset 11 that needs to be copied to offset 16 first, and you will instead end up with something like this:

```
destination : Be my frienfrienfrienfri
```

By copying backwards, you avoid that problem.  A simple conditional jump with the appropriate `dec` or `sub` operators will work fine.

After making room for the source string as specified above, its a simple matter of loading the registers properly and using `rep movsb` to copy the source into the destination at the specified position, overwriting the characters you have already copied.

And with that, `destination` will contain `"Be my good friend today"`.

Comment: Thanks, this is relly helpful @Matt Jordan

Answer (score 0):

You should reserve memory for a new "string" with the length og the original string+the length of the string to insert. Next copy characters from the source string, up to the position specified (use LODSB or LODSW depending on character width). point eds to the new output string and point edi to the source array. set CX to the value in position. This will copy the characters from the source to the new destination memory. Then point edi to the string to insert and set cx to the length of the string to insert. Run LODSW again and finally point edi to the position of the source string and set cx to the length of the source string minus the position and run lodsw a final time.

Comment: You should reserve memory for a new "string" with the length og the original string+the length of the string to insert. How should I do this? I should not use LODSB and LODSB :-(

Comment: Do you mean `movsb`?  `lodsb` just loads `al`, it doesn't store.  Either way, using `lodsb` or `movsb` without a rep prefix is only good for saving code size.  @Keihan: Just write a loop that copies bytes the normal way.  `lodsb` is just `mov al, [esi]` and `inc [esi]`.

Answer (score 0):

To a new string:

copy characters from the original, then copy in the new characters, then copy the tail of the original.

---

In-place:

copy the tail of the string to make a gap to store the new string.  This is like `memmove`: since the source and destination of the copy overlap, you should start from the last character, so you aren't overwriting characters you haven't copied yet.  It's also the same as [InsertionSort's copying to make room for a new element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

---

You're probably going to want to use two registers to keep track of source position and destination position.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with two functions : the first function shifts the characters of the string one position to the right starting at SI position, the second function calls the first one CX times. These functions are necessary to make room to insert the new string (I guess you can merge them into one function). After that, it's easy to overwrite the destination string with the source string. I chose "$" to finish the strings, you can change it by zeroes or something else :

**shift_right_once**

```
;---------------------------------------------------
;SHIFTS ONE POSITION TO THE RIGHT ALL THE CHARACTERS
;OF A STRING STARTING AT POSITION POINTED BY "SI".
;STRING MUST FINISH WITH "$".
;EXAMPLE: SI = 6
;      INPUT = 'Be my friend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;     OUTPUT = 'Be my ffriend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;MODIFIED REGISTERS : AX, SI.

shift_right_once proc   
    mov  al, [ si ]    ;FIRST CHAR TO START PROCESS.
shifting:
    cmp  al, '$'       
    je   end_shifting  ;IF ( END OF STRING )
    inc  si
    mov  ah, [ si ]
    mov  [ si ], al
    xchg al, ah
    jmp  shifting
end_shifting:    
    ret
shift_right_once endp
```

**shift_right_cx**

```
;---------------------------------------------------
;SHIFTS "CX" POSITIONS TO THE RIGHT ALL THE CHARACTERS
;OF A STRING STARTING AT POSITION POINTED BY "SI".
;STRING MUST FINISH WITH "$".
;EXAMPLE: SI = 6
;         CX = 3
;      INPUT = 'Be my friend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;     OUTPUT = 'Be my ffffriend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;MODIFIED REGISTERS : AX, CX.

shift_right_cx proc
    push si
    call shift_right_once      ;CALL PREVIOUS FUNCTION.
    pop  si
    loop shift_right_cx    
    ret
shift_right_cx endp
```

Next little program (made with EMU8086) shows how to use them :

```
.stack 100h

.data

destination db 'Be my friend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
source      db 'good $'
length      dw 5             ;LENGTH OF "SOURCE".
position    dw 6             ;POSITION TO INSERT.

.code
    mov  ax, @data
    mov  ds, ax    
    mov  es, ax    

;SHIFT CHARS TO THE RIGHT TO MAKE ROOM FOR NEW STRING.
    mov  cx, length           ;HOW MANY CHARS TO PUSH.
    mov  si, offset destination
    add  si, position
    call shift_right_cx

;OVERWRITE OLD CHARS WITH THE NEW ONES.
    mov  cx, length           ;HOW MANY NEW CHARS.
    mov  di, si               ;DI = DESTINATION.
    mov  si, offset source    ;SI = SOURCE.
    rep  movsb                ;DO { [DI]=[SI] } WHILE CX>0.

;WAIT FOR A KEY.
    mov  ah, 0
    int  16h        

;FINISH PROGRAM.    
    mov  ax, 4c00h
    int  21h        

;---------------------------------------------------
;SHIFTS "CX" POSITIONS TO THE RIGHT ALL THE CHARACTERS
;OF A STRING STARTING AT POSITION POINTED BY "SI".
;STRING MUST FINISH WITH "$".
;EXAMPLE: SI = 6      |
;         CX = 3
;      INPUT = 'Be my friend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;     OUTPUT = 'Be my ffffriend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;MODIFIED REGISTERS : AX, CX.

shift_right_cx proc
    push si
    call shift_right_once ;SHIFT RIGHT CHARACTERS ONCE.
    pop  si
    loop shift_right_cx    
    ret
shift_right_cx endp

;---------------------------------------------------
;SHIFTS ONE POSITION TO THE RIGHT ALL THE CHARACTERS
;OF A STRING STARTING AT POSITION POINTED BY "SI".
;STRING MUST FINISH WITH "$".
;EXAMPLE: SI = 6      |
;      INPUT = 'Be my friend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;     OUTPUT = 'Be my ffriend today$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
;MODIFIED REGISTERS : AX, SI.

shift_right_once proc   
    mov  al, [ si ]    ;FIRST CHAR TO START PROCESS.
shifting:
    cmp  al, '$'       
    je   end_shifting  ;IF ( END OF STRING )
    inc  si
    mov  ah, [ si ]
    mov  [ si ], al
    xchg al, ah
    jmp  shifting
end_shifting:    
    ret
shift_right_once endp
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is assembly language; there's no compiler to optimize away repeated copies.  You have to write efficient code in the first place.  Repeatedly copying one position to the right is more complicated and way slower than just copying the right number of positions in one go.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that's why I suggested to merge them (third line of first paragraph).

Comment: Ah, I only skimmed that.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the important thing about my answer is the algorithm, nobody else posted the algorithm in real assembly. Now anyone can use it and improve it.